# projecting a velocity vector into the xy-plane has a constant length

Tags: calculus

Given the curve described by $g(t) = (\sin(2t), 2\sin^2(t), 2\cos(t))$ lies on a sphere centered at the origin in $R^3$. Find the elngth of the velocity vector $v(t)$ and show that the projection of this vector into the xy-plane has a constant length.

The length of the velocity vector is calculated by taking the derivative of $g(t)$ then its norm.

Hence:

$g'(t) = (2\cos(2t), 4\cos(t), -2\sin(t))$

Then
$|g'(t)| = \sqrt{4\cos^2(2t)+16\cos^2+4\sin^2(t)} = 2\sqrt{\cos^2(2t)+4\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)}$

However how can I project this vector into an xy-plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there is a small mistake in your calculation of the velocity vector. The derivative of $2 \sin^2(t)$ is $ 4 \cos(t) \sin(t)$, not $4 \cos(t)$.
The projection of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the xy-plane can be thought of as the shadow that would result on the xy-plane from shining a light from perpendicularly above it on the vector. You get this projection by simply considering the $x$- and $y$- component of your vector, so in this case,
$$ \text{proj}_{xy}(\vec{v}(t)) = (2 \cos(2t), 4 \cos(t) \sin(t)).$$
To prove that is has constant length, you just calculate the Euclidean norm of it as you did already for the complete velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your g' is wrong, the second component should be $2sin(t)*cos(t)$ or $sin^2(t)$ if the second component of g(t) is $2sin^2(t)$

Projection on the x-y plain: just set the z component zero